# Work with HTML page elements that don't have classes or IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do two different things with some page elements, and unfortunately this is a little above my experience level. I'm hopeful some of the great people here are able to help me like they have in the past.

As a quick explanation of what I am doing: I am using a system that doesn't allow us to directly modify many of the files, though they do allow some things to be changed, including the addition of custom JS to pages.

Here's an example of the HTML code from the page:

```
<table id="sortabletbl1" class="datatable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th width="20"></th>
         <th width="20"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>07/03/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3606','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #1</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3606"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3606')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 13:08</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3571','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #2</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3571"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3571')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 09:48</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3555','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #3</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3555"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3555')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3518','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #4</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3518"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3518')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to do is to get the message ID, found in the second column of each row, and run a javascript function using that ID. Then, based on the results of that function, I need to write some text back to the page, adding it to the end of the second column. If the table cells had IDs I would know how to do this, but they don't, and there's no way to add them.

I'm going to grab the message ID, look it up in a database, then add a text label after the message subject based on the database results.

So, and example could be something like this:

```
  <tr>
     <td>07/03/2017 00:00</td>
     <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3606','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #1 - CATEGORY2</a></td>
     <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3606"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
     <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3606')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Notice the addition of " - CATEGORY2" to the end of the subject.

1. How can I grab the message ID of each message on the page and run a function using it?
2. How can I then write back to the proper table column once I run the function and get a result?

Thank you VERY much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery:

1. How can I grab the message ID of each message on the page and run a function using it?

   ```
   $('tr :nth-child(2)').each(function(i, td) {
          var $td = $(td);
          var match = /.*id=([0-9]+).*/g.exec($('a', $td).attr('onclick'));
          if (match) {
            var id = match[1];
            console.log("id is " + id);
          }
   });
   ```
2. How can I then write back to the proper table column once I run the function and get a result?

   `$td.text($td.text() + " - " + myResult);`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr :nth-child(2)').each(function(i, td) {
       var $td = $(td);
       var match = /.*id=([0-9]+).*/g.exec($('a', $td).attr('onclick'));
       if (match) {
         var id = match[1];
         console.log("id is " + id);
         // do my custom stuff
         var myResult = "CATEGORY " + new Date().getTime();
         $td.text($td.text() + " - " + myResult);
       } else {
         console.log("No Id found");
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sortabletbl1" class="datatable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th width="20"></th>
         <th width="20"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>07/03/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3606','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #1</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3606"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3606')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 13:08</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3571','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #2</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3571"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3571')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 09:48</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3555','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #3</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3555"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3555')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3518','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #4</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3518"><img src="images/icons/resendemail.png" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3518')"><img src="images/delete.gif" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Getting an error with this part I think: var $td = $(td);

Comment: Console says a variable name is missing, and shows that line like this:  var  = $(td);

Comment: Did you try the snippet? It has no errors. You can rename the variable if its not working for you

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. Now I just need to add in my custom JS code and it should be fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can grab all anchors or tables cells (with `document.querySelectorAll('td')`) and filter them by their innerText with regex. Also use regex capture groups to retrieve the id easily.

Writing to the specific element is easy: `el.innerText = el.innerText + 'appended string'` (where el is a dom element).

Comment: Do you know how, in jQuery, I can get "the second TD in each TR"?

Comment: I think you can select second node of any element with `el.childNodes[1]`

Comment: The first TR and it's second TD `$('tr')[0].childNodes[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the elements by tag name in JavaScript, like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("sortabletbl1"); 
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

The variable `cells` will be array and you then access the second element:

```
var messageCell = cells[i];
```

You can then access the text node and use REGEX like suggested by Rustem Kakimov.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, to access every second cell inside **each** row, you can use selector `#table tr td:nth-child(2)`.

I prepared a snippet below to show how it could be done.

```js
$(function(){
  var $table = $('#sortabletbl1');
  var $secondColumnCells = $table.find('tr td:nth-child(2)');
  
  $secondColumnCells.each(function(){
    var $cell = $(this);
    
    // Parse text in our column
    var oldText = $cell.text();
    var onclick = $cell.find('a').attr('onclick');
    var messageId = /id=(\d+)/.exec(onclick)[1];
    var messageNo = /#(\d+)/.exec(oldText)[1];
    
    // Prepare and set new text
    var newText = oldText + ' | ' + getMessageStatus(messageId) + ' | Inside row ' + $cell.parent().index() + ' | For ' + messageNo;
    $cell.text(newText);
  });
});

var getMessageStatus = function(messageId) {
  return 'State for ' + messageId;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="sortabletbl1" class="datatable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th width="20"></th>
         <th width="20"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>07/03/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3571','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #12</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Resend</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 13:08</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3215','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #23</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Resend</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 09:48</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3451','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #34</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Resend</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3555','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #45</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Resend</a></td>
         <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Trying this out now, will let you know.

Comment: I seem to get errors in cases where JS variables start with a $, like with. Firefox tells me a variable name is missing.

Comment: Everything works for me in Firefox 38. Perhaps you forgot to include jQuery or other library on your page is using dollar sign as well? In the latter case you can use `jQuery` viariable instead of `$`. Is example working when you click *Run code snippet* on SO?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use jQuery for this simple task. Nor do you need to juggle with regexes. Just plain simple JavaScript would do. This question isn't tagged jQuery anyway.

> get the message ID, found in the second column of each row, and run a
>   javascript function using that ID.

1. Your table already has an `id`, use that to select it:

   `var table = document.getElementById('sortabletbl1');`
2. You would need to get the `anchor` element from each of the `td` which are third in a row, but omit the first row. Use a CSS selector, in the `querySelectorAll`:

   `var emailCells = table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(:nth-child(1)) td:nth-child(3)');`

Where, `tr:not(:nth-child(1))` will select all `tr` which are not the first child. And then `td:nth-child(3)` will select all `td`s within those rows which are third-child.

You are currently using `th` in your first row, so this may not be required. You can straight away use `td`. But, I've shown you just in case. You can simply that by:

```
var emailCells = table.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)');
```

3. Run a simple iteration on the nodelist that is returned from the `querySelectorAll`.

Like this:

```
for (i=0; i < emailCells.length; i++ ) {
    var anchor = emailCells[i].firstChild;
    result.push(anchor.search.split('=').pop());
}
```

Where, the `firstChild` of that `td` is the `a`nchor element. This anchor element exposes the `location` object via its `href`. Use the `search` property of the `location` object to get the querystring portion of the url.

This is done by `anchor.search`. Now split this on the `=` character and get the last element of the resulting array. This last element is your `emailid`. This is done by `anchor.search.split('=').pop()`. Push this into a `result` array for later use.

> grab the message ID, look it up in a database, then add a text label
>   after the message subject based on the database results

4. Once you have that array, use that in any function call and process. Once you get back the results, use the same mechanism to replace the `textContent` of the `a`nchor of the second `td` of all rows starting from second row.

Like this:

```
anchor.textContent = anchor.textContent + ': ' + result[i];
```

**A demo snippet**:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('sortabletbl1'), 
 emailCells = table.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)'), 
 subjectCells = table.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)'), 
 result = []
;

for (i=0; i < emailCells.length; i++ ) {
 var anchor = emailCells[i].firstChild;
 result.push(anchor.search.split('=').pop());
}
for (i=0; i < subjectCells.length; i++ ) {
 var anchor = subjectCells[i].firstChild;
 anchor.textContent = anchor.textContent + ': ' + result[i];
}
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; } 
img { width: 16px; } 
th { text-align: left; }
```

```html
<table id="sortabletbl1" class="datatable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th width="20"></th>
         <th width="20"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>07/03/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3606','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #1</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3606"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/33d" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3606')"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/d33" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 13:08</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3571','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #2</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3571"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/33d" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3571')"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/d33" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 09:48</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3555','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #3</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3555"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/33d" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3555')"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/d33" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>28/02/2017 00:00</td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="window.open('messages.php?&amp;displaymessage=true&amp;id=3518','email_window','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return false">Message Subject #4</a></td>
         <td><a href="resendmessage.php?resend=true&amp;emailid=3518"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/33d" alt="Resend Email" border="0"></a></td>
         <td><a href="#" onclick="doDelete('3518')"><img src="//placehold.it/32x32/d33" alt="Delete" height="16" border="0" width="16"></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```